# Filtering JSON with apache spark (NO SPARK SQL) - Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying apply a filter to a json stream of data coming from a Kafka Direct Stream. 
I'm using `net.liftweb lift-json_2.11` to parse a sample JSON `{"type": "fast", "k":%d}`.
This is my code:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))

val s1 = stream.map(record => parse(record.value))
```

The result of `s1.print()` is:

```
...
JObject(List(JField(type,JString(fast)), JField(k,JInt(11428))))
JObject(List(JField(type,JString(fast)), JField(k,JInt(11429))))
JObject(List(JField(type,JString(fast)), JField(k,JInt(11430))))
...
```

How can I apply a spark filter on the `k` field? For example:
`k%2==0`

I don't want to use SparkSQL because I need to apply also Joins on streams of data and SparkSQL does not allow me to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just apply a `.filter` to your `stream.map(record => parse(record.value))`?

Comment: Define a case class that represents the JSON entry, e.g. `case class Entry(type: String, k: Int)`, then use `parse(record.value).extract[Entry]` to get a stream of `Entry`s. The filtering should boil down to simply doing `s1.filter(e => e.k % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: @HristoIliev If i try that I get a `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` error

Comment: Solved. I define the class as @HristoIliev suggests. But was not enough to add `.extract[Entry]` after `parse`. the `stream.map` now is: `val s1 = stream.map(record => {implicit val formats = DefaultFormats \ parse(record.value).extract[Entry]})`

Comment: Please write an answer containing your full solution and accept it for the sake of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
//spark import
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream

//kafka import
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe

//json library import
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}

object App {

  def main(args : Array[String]) {

// Create the context with a 1 second batch size
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkScript").setMaster("local[4]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

case class MySens(elem: String, k: Int, pl: String)

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "group.id" -> "test_luca",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics1 = Array("fast-messages")

val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics1, kafkaParams))

val s1 = stream.map(record => {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  parse(record.value).extract[MySens]
}
)

val p1 = s1.filter {e => e.k.%(10)==0}

p1.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}

}
```